# Meteor-rxjs ObservableCursor as observable unsubscribe

Tags: angular, meteor, rxjs, observable

### Setup

Currently, I'm using angular2 + meteor and meteor-rxjs package.

### Description

The `meteor-rxjs` package wrap `ObservableCursor` with an RXJS observable, I can easily subscribe to the collection and bind the dataset to the `items` variable in the component.

Everything is fine until I want to unsubscribe the current set of data and query another set of data using different mongo selector in `Collection.find()`. The expected outcome is only the updates from currently subscribed data will affect the value of `items`, but now the previous subscription will also update the value of `items` when it has any changes.

### Question

I suspect the previous subscription is NOT unsubscribed. How can I unsubscribe the `Observable` and the underlying mongo cursor of `ObservableCursor`?

### Code

DBService.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Meteor } from 'meteor/meteor';

@Injectable()
export class DBService {

  constructor() {
    MeteorObservable.subscribe('collection_name').subscribe();
  }

  public getItems(callback: (value) => void): Subscription {

    // do query
    let subscription = Emails.find({/* some selector */}).zone().subscribe(
      (items) => {
        return callback(items);
      }
    );
    return subscription;
  }
}
```

component.ts

```
import 'reflect-metadata';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

import { DBService } from 'db.service';

@Component({
  .....
})
export class EmailComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  private subscription: Subscription;
  private items;

  constructor(private dbService: DBService) {}

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription = this.dbService.getItems((items) => this.items = items);
  }

  public ngOnDestroy(): void {
    // unsubscribe
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

### Reference

https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-rxjs